# How to add to a saved NSUserDefault?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I am making a game in Xcode which in includes a scoring system in each level. Here I have some code that gets an NSString (passedValue1) by using a delegate.

Then i add the code to receive the value in my viewDidLoad and display my value in a UILabel

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
    { 


        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib
        NSString *key=@"labelKey";

        if(passedValue1){
            NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

            NSObject * object = [prefs valueForKey:key];
            if(object != nil){
                NSUserDefaults *defults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                [defults setValue:passedValue1 forKey:key];
                [defults synchronize];
            }
            else{
                NSUserDefaults *defults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

                NSInteger readScore=[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:key] integerValue];
                NSInteger newValue=readScore+[passedValue1 integerValue];
                [defults setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",newValue] forKey:key];
                [defults synchronize];

            }
        }
        label.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:key];
    }
```

Once I have displayed the value I then save it into a label using a NSUserDefault. However, once I have replayed my game and have another score value I would like to add the new passedValue1 value to the currently saved value...

**For example:**
say I play my level and I get the score value of 10. The value is then saved and I replay my level. I would then like to take the saved value and add it to the value i just scored. So thats say the second value I have scored is 20. I would then like my code to add them together and give me a value of 30.
can anyone help because the code I'm using does not correctly do the function that I want to do which is add the previous and the currently passed value.

What is wrong with my code??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you perform above scenario then what you are getting means old value or new value or anything else?

Comment: once check with break points which weather condition satisfied or not in your point of you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use `valueForKey:` for this (it's not what you might think it is, see *Key-Value Coding*). Instead, you should use `objectForKey:` or in your case `integerForKey:`.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSInteger value = [defaults integerForKey:key];
value += [passedValue1 integerValue];
[defaults setInteger:value forKey:key];
BOOL success = [defaults synchronize];
```

Comment: (+1) This is much simpler code, and would also solve the problem of the wrong `if` condition, because `integerForKey` defaults to zero.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you got your `if` condition wrong, it should be

```
if (object == nil) { // <-- you have object != nil here !
    // save new value
} else {
    // read old value, add something, save new value
}
```